# Formatting issue in text and html file while using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I  am using jQM and Jquery .Actually I have facing one problem of formatting.

The problem is that .I display the text from server first Time like that .

Example

```
Hello my name is anjali
Hi my name is rohit
go for tea?
```

It is real time data so close my connection and save this data on .txt file and .html file(of same name).But when i saw this data on html or txt file it look like this

```
Hello my name is anjali hi my name is rohit go for tea?
```

In a single line.
So when i read from html or text file it show in same as in text file?
can you please give some idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Whitespace in html isn't important. You'll need to add a `<br>` after each line or wrap each line in an element, probably a `<p>`.

Comment: actually while saving file it is too too touch to add br because data is coming from server it's real time..:(

Answer (score 0):

Open the resulting text in some HEX editor (F3 then 3 in Total Commander will do) and look if there is any line ending character or just space.

Comment: actually i am display the same text or html file on device.But it show in same line.

Comment: I think the issue of saving .If i save the file in same format then i read the file same.?

Comment: @Rohit you should check it in a hex editor, some software don't support all kind ot the line endings (like Notepad in Windows 7) and it could be your issue... do you have any code sample?

Comment: text file ?  wait ok doing